# Magento 2 - product collection filtered with custom attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, collection

I would like to filter `product collection` on category page using custom attribute. For example:

On category page, I want to list only products that have custom attribute `age` set to `10`.

How to achieve that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make preference of this class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

and go to its `_getProductCollection()` method and put your attribute filter condition after this line

`$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();`

for example

```
  $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
  $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('age', 10);
```

**Update**

In case of `MagentoCE2.2` that method would be `initializeProductCollection()`

Comment: I'm in version 2.2, which I/m working in that line is in function initializeProductCollection(). Worked fines. Thanks!

Comment: You are always welcome @PeteJaworski

Comment: This is private method so we can't override this.we can change private to public but don't want to make any changes in core file so how can modify the method  "initializeProductCollection()".

Comment: When we apply a filter on category product collection the products will display as we needed but the Layered navigation display will not be driven from the loaded collection but it was driven from the whole category products. So, how to resolve this issue.?

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, how can we filter collection with multi-select attribute?

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala,initializeProductCollection is a private method, can you pls update the full code?

Comment: I had to downvote as initializeProductCollection() is private.

Comment: How we can apply same addAttributeToFilter for layered navigation?@Murtuza Zabuawala

Comment: @ZealousWeb this will not apply in layered navigation for that you can check `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Category/ItemCollectionProvider` class

Answer (score 2):

For the drop-down attribute, We can filter using drop-down option ID instead of Label.

Your code is like below.

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('age', 10)
    ->load();
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Which class plugin shall I use it in?